# how to call MS Graph Search API for get SharePoint list items using postman

Tags: search, sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I called ms search api in Post man using Azure AD APP, I assigned Application permission with `sites.read.all` permission to Azure AD app, and passed that azure app token for call search.

I am getting below error message

> SearchRequest Invalid (Region is required when request with
> application permission)  Region is required when request with
> application permission.

Detail: Azure App have Application level permission with `sites.read.all`

Request in Postman

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
Request header : Content-Type: application/json
"queryString": "Charging Cradle 
path:\\https://SPSITE/sites/SITE1/Lists/LIST101
```

Authorization Token : I passed app token that have sites.read.all with Application level.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the /search/query [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-query?view=graph-rest-1.0) with application permissions, this endpoint does not yet support application permissions, only delegated permissions are currently supported.

[image]

You need to use delegated permission to make this API work.

Comment: Hi Dipesh, Thanks for quick response .I created azure ad app with both application and delegated permissions, how I can call in Postman or graph explorer or any sample of react app.

Comment: I tried to call in postman , but getting above message or some time access denied

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation about how to search with application permissions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-searchall?view=graph-rest-1.0

In the request body you must specify region property

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
          "listItem"
      ],
       "query": {
        "queryString": "contoso"
      },
      "region": "NAM"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the region value your tenant admin needs to call (copy&paste in the browser) the URL bellow otherwise you will receive `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/_api/GeoTenantInstanceInformationCollection
```